# Jquery find and replace Tag with some string

Tags: jquery

I have span with id "bar".which contains tag `<h3></h3>` and I want to replace `<h3></h3>` with "some string". Here is my html

```
<span id="bar" >
<h3></h3>
</span>
```

Output I am expecting as

```
<span id="bar" >
some string
</span>
```

Many Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your `some string` contains html tags use `html`, otherwise `text`

```
var someString = "Some String";

$("span#bar:has(h3)").text(someString);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `html` method:

```
$('#bar').html('some string');
```

If you want to just replace the h3 element, you can use `replaceWith` method:

```
$('#bar h3').replaceWith('some string');
```

Comment: In this case can be used `html()` method, but maybe the span will contains some other tags which should not be replaced and I think the best method is to use `replaceWith()` method

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#bar h3').replaceWith('some string');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code,

```
var someString = "Some String";

$("span#bar:has(h3)").replaceWith(someString);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sLT7f/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $('#bar').html();
    text = text.replace("<h3></h3>", "some string");
    $('#bar').html(text);
```